# Finding display state of a dynamic property

Tags: python, scripting, properties

There is a BoolProperty p defined in a custom **PropertyGroup** class; and p is displayed in a panel based on some conditions (say cond1).

Later in the code, I need to find out whether p was displayed in the panel or not. (And it's cumbersome to repeat the cond1 check everywhere.)

How to find this out? (The params.p gives me access to only the value of the property (True / False) and not other attributes like its visibility.)

Comment: Store the result of the conditional check in a instance attribute that can be accessed from the other classes.

Comment: @rjg The condition is dependent on the selection of EnumProperty in the same panel. So no use storing it.